# How to enable auto import for custom Angular library in WebStorm / PhpStorm?

Tags: angular, intellij-idea, phpstorm, webstorm, angular-library

I'm trying to create an Angular 9 library with some components and classes I use in different projects. What I did:

1. `ng new my-lib-project --create-application=false`
2. `cd my-lib-project`
3. `ng generate library my-lib --prefix lb`
4. I created a test-class.ts file in `projects/my-lib/src/lib/` with an easy LibTestClass definition (see below)
5. I added the line `export * from './lib/test-class';` to the public-api.ts file.
6. I called `ng build my-lib` and copied the result to `myOtherProject/node_modules/`

**Problem:** when I type `const test = new LibTestClass();` in the app.component.ts file of the myOtherProject, PhpStorm does not show the import hint to easily add the import line for TestClass. How can I make this auto import work for my custom library?

**Further information:**

- IDE: PhpStorm 2020.1.1
- OS: MacOS
- Angular: 9.1.6
- my-lib is not released to npm

**test-class.ts:**

```
export class LibTestClass {

  private test = '';

  constructor() {}
}
```

Comment: did you add `my-lib` to the `package.json` of `myOtherProject`? Indirect dependencies (the ones that are not listed in `package.json`) are not indexed, so no completion/auto-import/etc is available

Comment: @lena, I did not add my-lib to the package.json, because I thought I don't have to. How can I add it if my-lib is not released to npm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @lena I found the answer: In order to enable import hints for your Angular library you have to install a (local) dependency to your library build. In my case the solution is:

```
npm install --save ../my-lib-project/dist/my-lib
```

This creates a link to the local build of your library and is updated automatically when you build your library. I recommend to use `ng build --watch`in development.